# Gnome extensions give me error when updating

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I update my GNOME extensions under [this URL](https://extensions.gnome.org/local/) with the Chrome plugin

Every time I log back into Ubuntu 18.04  I get a notification, saying that there are updates for my GNOME extensions. But when I click on the green button to update, I always get an error message, that does not disappear until I reboot my machine.

I get that an update MIGHT break something, but that 3 or more extensions give me an error at the same time is very unlikely. Sounds more like a problem with my system.

Why could this be?

[image]

Comment: We have no idea what Ubuntu version, and thus what version of Gnome Shell you are running. Many extensions may be installed using apt or synaptic package manager

Comment: Updated. I installed them through the chrome extension.

Comment: Just try removing and re-adding the problematic extensions.

Comment: @pomsky I cant even do that.

Comment: I encountered the same problem and I did a full software update, rebooted my PC then it worked.

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04 while trying to update GSConnect. Uninstalling works, but then I cannot install it again -> ERROR.

Answer (score 3):

It has happened to me too on `Ubuntu 20.04.1` each time I have updated a gnome-shell extension using the firefox gnome-shell integration plugin.

If you dig into the system logs you will discover that there is nothing to worry about:

```
sudo journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-shell | grep -i 'error.*extension'
nov 17 12:38:48 sunyata gnome-shell[1699]: JS ERROR: Extension wsmatrix@martin.zurowietz.de: Error: A different version was loaded previously. You need to log out for changes to take effect.
dec 14 09:44:26 sunyata gnome-shell[1985]: JS ERROR: Extension nightthemeswitcher@romainvigier.fr: Error: A different version was loaded previously. You need to log out for changes to take effect.
```

As you can read, the *error* is actually just a **warning**. `gnome-shell` is reporting:

`A different version (of the extension, N/A) was loaded previously. You need to log out for changes to take effect.`

So, no need to worry about it. The error will disappear at the next login (either after log out or reboot).

If you want to make it disappear immediately you can force gnome-shell to reload extensions restarting it:

<kbd>alt + f2</kbd> `# to execute a command`

<kbd>r</kbd> then <kbd>enter</kbd> `# restart gnome-shell`

I hope this information will be useful to the error-free-systems maniacs like me :)

Comment: This is a good workaround on X11, but [restarting the shell does not work when running Wayland](https://superuser.com/questions/1164174/how-can-i-restart-the-gnome-shell-on-wayland).